# Is taking the address of an undefined function allowed?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, function-pointers, one-definition-rule

The following code defines the entire program. Is this program standard conformant (with the latest version)?

```
void foo();

int main()
{
    auto x = &foo;
    return 0;
}
```

[Here](https://godbolt.org/z/NLXLK9) is a convenience shortcut.

This code has no practical use, I'm just curious.

Comment: This should cause a linker error (unless the useless statement is eliminated completely by the compiler) as you are asking for the address of something that is not fully defined.

Comment: You are just seeing some sort of optimization. When trying to use `x` in some way, it doesn't compile: https://godbolt.org/z/DaisTo

Comment: @500-InternalServerError should've checked that. The linker throws an error if I disable optimization.

Comment: An undefined reference normally makes a program ill-formed NDR. Since I doubt a compiler is required to check if `x` is used or not, it should apply here too.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - There is nothing preventing the compiler from checking if `x` is used either.   The standard doesn't prevent a compiler from eliminating variables (like `x`), or evaluation of expressions that initialise them (`&foo`), if it can detect there are no side-effects of the initialisation or usage of the variable.  The "as if" rule only requires observable behaviour to be the same.   Since `foo()` is not defined in the program the behaviour is undefined, no diagnostic required - and one possible manifestation of that is a linker error (missing symbol `foo()`) but that is not required

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Every function that is odr-used requires a definition](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#10.sentence-1) (no diagnostic required). Taking the address of a function is an odr-use, so this program exhibits undefined behaviour. With optimisations, the address-of is optimised out so it doesn't have a linker error, but it's not required to work.